# 二つ下のいとこ instead of はとこ

Tags: translation, word-usage, reading-comprehension

I'm trying to understand the usage of 二つ下 in the following sentence.

シンちゃんは私の二つ下のいとこです

When I read it without 下 it sounds like:

Shin-chan is my second cousin or something along those lines.

The issues is I don't understand the usage of 二つ let alone 二つ下 in this sentence.

Wouldn't it usually be written as シンちゃんの私のはとこです

I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Some of those were intentionally typed. はとこ is a word for second cousin.

Comment: Oops. Uh, not sure which is suppose to be which, I’ll just undo my edit.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/26225/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 明鏡’s definition for 下:

> ❺ 地位・能力・程度・**年齢**などが劣っていること。また、その人。
>   「3歳下の弟」

Namely, 下 can refer to the fact that someone’s position, ability, level, or age is lower. In your case it’s age.

In the example it uses 歳 instead of つ for the counter, but つ (as well as 個) work for age just fine, albeit slightly informal.

Comment: I can see my mistake now, this sentence was just meant to be read as: My cousin Shin-chan is two years younger than me.　ありがとうございますダリウス先生！

Comment: How is 下 pronounced on this context?

Comment: @user3856370 した